# XSL: retrieve tag value

Tags: xslt

I have a special case because I need to check current value with preceding one.
In some cases the tag doesn't contain a value.

Sample XML:

```
<Row>
        <Cell column="Contrat">
            <Type>String</Type>
            <Value>blabla</Value>
        </Cell>
        <Cell column="Dossier">
            <Type>String</Type>
            <Value>monitoring</Value>
        </Cell>
        <Cell column="DocVersion" />
        <Cell column="CodeAffaire">
            <Type>String</Type>
            <Value>AF1302740</Value>
        </Cell>
</Row>
```

In this case how can i detect that the tag `DocVersion` is without a value ?

Comment: By checking for the existence of `Value`, e.g. `<xsl:if test="not(Value)">do something</xsl:if>`. Please post a [mcve] including the expected result if you need a fuller answer.

Comment: It's fine, you answered me. Thank you Marc